# Should there be a "generalist" badge on Stack Exchange itself?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, generalist-badge

A person that is a programmer, a cook, a physicist and a whatever participant on Stack Exchange and has sufficient reputation points sounds much more like a generalist than one knowing different programming languages.

I would propose having badges not only on the sites individually or on Area 51, but also on Stack Exchange. One such badge would be "generalist".

Comment: Sigh, don't we spend enough time on one site already?

Answer (score 5):

- `Generalist` - has more than {x} upvotes on non-wiki answers on {y} SE sites
- `Polymath` - is in the top 5% reputation-wise on five SE sites
- `Universal Genius` - is or was on page 1 on five SE sites at the same time

Maybe sites would have to have reached some degree of maturity - say, six months' age or a certain amount of traffic - to be counted. Otherwise, the badges could be achieved just by being very active on some young SE sites.

Comment: +1 for the Generalist tag.  The others seem far too arbitrary as they currently stand - it seems that it would just be down to luck whether you managed to get on page 1 with all five sites at the same time, or whatever.

Comment: @Steve funny, I like the two others better because they "scale": It's harder to achieve the badges through some accidentally massively upvoted contributions on some young site whose audience has no clear rules yet on what is good content. The page order and reputation leagues don't fluctuate *that* heavily, I think it would be an acceptable measure.

Comment: so make it "... on non-Beta sites." Anyway, silly to get a badge for a site that may not be around next week...